# The base of my shower stall is pulling away from the wall and allowing water to leak how do I reseal it?

Tags: plumbing

The base is flexing away from the wall and the caulking will no longer hold due to the movement is there a caulking that will allow for flexibility?
We just had the shower kit replaced about 4 years ago

Comment: A photo would  help

Comment: Sounds like the shower base was not properly bedded when installed, if it's flexing. It shouldn't be flexing.